# Twitter Search API with MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, twitter, tweets

I want to use Twitter Search API to get tweets and store them in MongoDB.
Using `GET` I can do it

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%3A%29&lang=en&rpp=100&result_type=mixed
```

But how can I store those tweets in MongoDB?
I've tried this one but no results....

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'mongo'


con = Mongo::Connection.new
db = con.db('sentiment')
tweets = db.collection('positive')

uri = URI.parse('http://search.twitter.com/search.json')
uri.query_values = { :q => "%3A%29", :lang => "en" ,:rpp=>"100",:result_type=>"mixed"}
json = open(uri).read
ref = JSON.parse(json)
ref["results"].each do |tweet|
  puts "@" + tweet["from_user"] + " : " + tweet["text"]
end
```

Getting this one as results:

> Thu Jul 26 20:08:38 [conn18] end connection 127.0.0.1:61861

Comment: You have `use_ssl` = True but are using http://search.twitter.com/ and you are also doing basic auth - not sure its needed.

Comment: I've updated the code but still even with it there is no results...just no connection...